# Activity restarts after returning from ad click

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

The game starts with the "Start" activity, and from there the user can pick a mode which will then launch the "Main" activity.  There is an ad banner on Main.  If I play the game for a bit, then click on the ad, then close the ad, everything that happened in Main is lost and Main is reset.  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Due to the memory your game is using. When ad is clicked current application is stopped, that means system can kill the app if short on memory.
2. "Don't Keep Activities" option is enabled in Developer Options in phone settings, due to which system kills every application once sent in background and recreate the activities on resume.

To handle this, You can save and resume current state of application in
    onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods of activity resp.